# "Line of research" or "research line"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Which one is more appropriate in USA English? "**Line of research**" or "**research line**"?

Also, if there are individual "lines of research" for each person, is it correct to say:

Everyone's **line** of research

or should I say:

Everyone's **lines** of research

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks two very different questions—one about whether "line of research" or "research line" is clearly preferred in normal English (answer: "line of research" is much more commonly used), and the other about whether "everyone's" takes a singular or a plural form of a noun in a situation where each possessor has only one of that noun (this question would require a fairly lengthy answer, but I'm sure it has been asked on EL&U in the past).

Comment: Ok! Thank you for explaining your reasons, @SvenYargs

Answer (score 2):

"Line of research" is a much more familiar term. "Research line" would likely mean something different, such as a product line that exists for doing research, or such as the viewpoint someone is taking in their research.

Yes, there can be multiple lines of research. One organization might have several, and even an individual researcher could have several lines of research. "Everyone's line of research" can refer to one more multiple lines of research; this isn't specific to lines of research, the same sort of ambiguity would exist if we were talking about everyone's bicycle or everyone's table.

Answer (score -1):

Line of research is more formal than research line.
If each person has more than one line of research, then you would refer to those tasks as everyone's lines of research because everybody has (lines).

Comment: If each person has only one line of research should I use: "Everyone's line of research"?

Comment: Yes - the plurality or singularity of the group is reflected in the phrase.

Comment: @nico if you want to accentuate the fact that there is one line per person, you could say "Each person's line of research" specifically. "Anyone's line of research" is fine, but does not narrow the meaning as much.